# Extending Python with C++ no SWIG

Tags: c++, python

OK so I have a C++ function with a header like this:

```
int myfunc(vector<int> a, vector<mystruct> b, vector<int> c)
```

I have written the wrapper code (using Python.h as I have done many times with C, which translates the Python data types into the vector datatypes and structs I use in my program). The problem is I don't know how to tell setup.py to compile it with g++, I get a bunch of errors when I run

```
setup.py build -i
```

My setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

setup(name="MyModule", version="1.0",
  ext_modules=[Extension("MyModule", ["myfunc.cpp"])])
```

Can anyone tell me how I can make the build process use g++ a not gcc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `language="c++"` to your Extension object:

```
Extension("MyModule", ["myfunc.cpp"], language="c++")
```

Comment: Nope still not working...I wish there was a good turoial o this with C++ not C...obviously it's not as easy as C...

Comment: Eventually I did manage to get it to work...the language part helped tho so I will mark this as answered...